# How to autoclose TPopUpMenu when mouse leaves it in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, popupmenu

In my app I have a `Label` and a `PopUpMenu`. When mouse enters in Label's area then its `onMouseEnter` popUps the menu. If I change my mind and want to close the menu without a choice, I must click somewhere out of it. How can I force menu to close with no clicking but just when the mouse leaves its area ? There isn't a `onMouseLeave` event that I can use

Comment: Just curious: How does your application work without a mouse? (For instance, if only a keyboard is connected to the PC.)

Comment: This is how Windows works. It is IMO a bad idea to have an application with a different behavior than the norm. You can hit ESC key or click out of the popupmenu. Also, the mouse is usually very close to the border of the popupmenu and can easily move outside of it when you don't want.

Comment: @fpiette. So there is no way to create a descendant that will have an onMouseLeave event?

Comment: @JimPapas: Everything is possible if you don't mind making it complicated and fragile. Now, Win32 popup menus are very much not designed to be used like this, so you'll likely need to make it complicated and fragile if you want to use Win32 menus. I'd instead create my own menu (borderless TForm) which would give me full control of its behaviour. Still, you need to ask yourself if this is a good design in the first place. (Personally, I find website and desktop app menus that close when I accidentally move my mouse away from them to be annoying.) And what if the user don't have a pointing dev?